# How to convert Xml files to Text Files

Tags: xml, text

I have around 8000 xml files that needs to be converted into text files. The text file must contain title, description and keywords of the xml file without the tags and removing other elements and attributes as well. In other words, i need to create 8000 text files containing the title,description and keywords of the xml file. I need codings for this to be done systematically. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at my sample over at my new post thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941510/how-to-convert-xml-files-to-text-files-2

Answer (score 4):

Going from XML to text smells like a job for XSLT - it's a XML-based transformation language that can take an XML input and convert it to anything text-based on the output side.

You can read up on XSLT on lots of websites - one of the better tutorials in the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) one.

Since you didn't post any sample XML, I have no clue what your XML looks like, and also no idea what your output should be. But assuming it would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <title>Some Title</title>
  <description>Some description</description>
  <keywords>
    <keyword>Keyword1</keyword>
    <keyword>Keyword2</keyword>
    <keyword>Keyword3</keyword>
    <keyword>Keyword4</keyword>
   </keywords> 
</root>
```

you could easily write a XSLT transformation to turn that into

**YourTextFile.txt**

```
Some Title
Some Description
Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4
```

or whatever other format you are looking for.

Comment: I had an itch to answer that xsl would be a good solution, except that every time I have had to implement xsl in the past it took plenty of work to make programming language x use xsl the way god intended. Always got it working mind you and with stellar results so +1.

Comment: Please take a look at my sample over at my new post thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941510/how-to-convert-xml-files-to-text-files-2

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use Python. You can use the interpreter to run the pattern while you are setting it up, command line goes along way in setting this sort of thing up properly. Assuming the xml is valid this should allow you the most flexibility with the least hassle.

so assuming the following xml format:

```
<root>
  <title>Document Title</title>
  <content>Some document content.</content>
  <keywords>test, document, keyword</keywords>
</root>
```

and assuming the output of each document should be:

```
Document Title

Some document content.

test, document, keyword
```

The python code might look something like:

```
import sys
import os
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def Readthexml(f):
    """Read the file from the argument list and dump the title contents and keywords"""
    xcontent = ElementTree()
    xcontent.parse(f)
    doc = [xcontent.find("title").text, xcontent.find("content").text, xcontent.find("keywords").text]
    out = open(f + ".txt", "w")
    out.write("\n\n".join(doc))
    return True

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
        args = argv[1:]
        for arg in args:
            if os.path.exists(arg):
                Readthexml(arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

from which you could generate a batch file to update files regularly (assuming it is a windows environment though python works in whatever).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities.  If it is simple XML you can read it like any other text file, filter out the angle brackets and add in your own strategically-placed punctuation.  Or, you can open up an XML reader and a text writer, and output it any way you want.

If you read the file names from the folder into a collection, you can loop through them and process all of the files automatically.

Comment: Hey Robert, Thanks for your reply. Do you mind if you can help me get some websites for reference because i'm really new to this topic and my supervisor is rushing me for it to be done. Thanks very much for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar issues when I copied text messages from my phone to a file and it was an .xml format and had symbols and characters in between each word and I wanted to edit those out.  So I downloaded Notepad++ and opened the .xml file in it.  Say you want to delete all instances of `<title>`.  You highlight (sample text) and the click Replace icon (it's a blue b→a icon in the tool bar at the top). It'll have the highlighted text in the "Find what" field and then you leave the "Replace With" field blank and choose Replace All and it'll get rid of all instances of (sample text).  Do that for all symbols and text and replace with what you want or it should be.  I had over 4800 lines and it worked great.

Comment: Doing this manually for 8000 files individually doesn't sound very fun.